# How to constantly consume and output messages from a stream using redis cli?

Tags: redis, redis-streams

How to constantly consume and output messages from a stream using redis cli?

I tried the command below, however it only consume the last one message but what I want from the redis cli is to constantly consume and output messages on the screen while the publisher is continuously publishing messages.

`XREAD BLOCK 0 STREAMS mystream $`

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, unlike the special modes for `MONITOR` and `SUBSCRIBE`, the redis-cli doesn't feature a "streaming" mode yet. Please feel free to propose the news feature by opening an issue at https://github.com/redis/redis/issues

Comment: Of course - just write a loop that does `XREAD` in your favorite programming language.

Comment: I feel like that will overload redis

Comment: lol - you'll need to work hard to overload Redis. Trust me, a single connection trying to read a stream one entry at a time isn't gonna do any harm, but feel free to test my claims :)

Comment: I would not read one at a time. I would try and read 50K entries if I can so I can get more throughput too.

Comment: Note that the `BLOCK` is release once there's a single message that can be delivered (i.e. `BLOCK n` + `COUNT m` will return one message).